# Compiler warning for multiple copy constructors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates, constructor

I want to use a custom class as the type for a boost::heap::fibonacci_heap and also be able to iterate and modify the elements of the heap. I'm experimenting with the code provided by [How to orderly traverse a Boost.Heap Priority Queue and update a given element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102406/how-to-orderly-traverse-a-boost-heap-priority-queue-and-update-a-given-element/15104309#15104309) .

I've come up with a working example, but my Visual Studio 2010 compilier warns me that my class EdgeHeap has multiple copy constructors ( [warning documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e02fwk4s.aspx) ).

Here's the warning (roughly):

```
filepath\boost\heap\fibonacci_heap.hpp(762): warning C4521: 'boost::heap::fibonacci_heap<T>': Multiple constructors
          with
          [
              T=EdgeHeap
          ]
```

I'm confused because I haven't declared any copy constructors, so the only ones should be those automatically added by the compiler. Where are the multiple constructors coming from? Also is this something that I should worry about?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/heap/fibonacci_heap.hpp>

class Edge
{
    public:
        int index;
        double weight;
        std::pair<int, int> vertices;

        Edge(int i, double w, int start, int end)
        {
            index = i;
            weight = w;
            vertices.first = start;
            vertices.second = end;
        }
};

class EdgeHeap
{
    typedef boost::heap::fibonacci_heap<EdgeHeap>::handle_type handle_t;

    public:
        handle_t handle;
        Edge data;

        EdgeHeap(const Edge &data_) : data(data_) {}

        bool operator<(EdgeHeap const & rhs) const
        {
            return data.weight < rhs.data.weight;
        }
};

void setup_handle(boost::heap::fibonacci_heap<EdgeHeap>::handle_type &&handle)
{
    (*handle).handle = handle;
}

int main()
{
    boost::heap::fibonacci_heap<EdgeHeap> heap;

    Edge e(0, 10, 0, 1);
    setup_handle(heap.push(e));
    Edge e1(1, 2, 1, 2);
    setup_handle(heap.push(e1));
    Edge e2(2, 80, 2, 0);
    setup_handle(heap.push(e2));

    std::find_if(heap.ordered_begin(), heap.ordered_end(),
    [&heap](const EdgeHeap &e) -> bool
    {
        if(e.data.index == 2)
        {
            const_cast<EdgeHeap &>(e).data.weight += 2;
            heap.increase(e.handle);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });

    std::for_each(heap.ordered_begin(), heap.ordered_end(),
    [](const EdgeHeap &e)
    {
        std::cout << e.data.weight << std::endl;
    });
}
```

Comment: pasting in the compiler messages would help

Comment: I've added the rough text. I translated it from German, so it may not be the exact English compiler equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the header, the `boost::heap::fibonacci_heap` [does have multiple copy constructors](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost/heap/fibonacci_heap.html) :

```
fibonacci_heap(fibonacci_heap const &);
fibonacci_heap(fibonacci_heap &);
```

(The compiler message is not about `EdgeHeap` or one of your types)

As per the [VS documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e02fwk4s.aspx), it is an informational warning, nothing to worry about in this case.