# Boost heap handle to top element

Tags: c++, boost, priority-queue

I have an algorithm which essentially takes elements of type `T`, pushes them to a `priority_queue`, and then takes the top element of the queue, modifies it, updates the heap, takes the (possibly new) top element, and so on.

I'd like to try the [Boost heap](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/heap.html) library to replace std::priority_queue to avoid having to update by a `pop` followed by a `push` of the same element. However, I cannot seem to find a way to access a handle to the top of the queue, to update it.

Specifically there seems to be only two ways to get a handle to an element:

1. `s_handle_from_iterator(it)`. However, the iterator returned by `begin()` is not necessarily the top of the stack, and this method does not take `ordered_iterator`, so it seems I'm out of luck?
2. `push(elem)` returns the handle. However, using that seems to mean that I have to store the handle somewhere, probably in the element itself, which seems like a waste of space (and time, when handling the elements).

Is there a better way?

Note that for a slightly different use case (iterating the whole heap in order) [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102406/how-to-orderly-traverse-a-boost-heap-priority-queue-and-update-a-given-element?rq=1) seems to suggest that there really isn't a better way...

Comment: `boost::fibonacci_heap` has `ordered_begin` function that allows You to get the min/max element in the heap. Maybe You should consider using it

Comment: @bartop yes, I know. See my point 1: I cannot turn that to a `handle_type`, and I need to modify the top element.

Comment: `ordered_begin` gives You the top elemen of `heap` so I don't see an issue with it

Comment: @bartop how do I modify that element, i.e. which handle do I pass to `update(handle)`?

Comment: `auto handle = fibonacci_heap::s_handle_from_iterator(heap.ordered_begin());` ought to do it

Comment: @bartop Doesn't work, it gives ` error: no matching function for call to 'boost::heap::fibonacci_heap<...>::s_handle_from_iterator(boost::heap::fibonacci_heap<...>::ordered_iterator)'`